# Why Rust complains about lifetime of types in functions that don't use instances of these types?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Rust requires lifetimes for types that don't have instances:

```
use futures::future::BoxFuture;

struct A{
    
}

impl A{

    async fn send_and_expect<T>(&mut self, unauthorized_retry: i32) -> std::result::Result<(),()>{
        Err(())        
    }
    
    fn send_and_expect_wrapper<'a, T>(&'a mut self, unauthorized_retry: i32) 
    -> BoxFuture<'a, std::result::Result<(),()>> {
        Box::pin(self.send_and_expect::<T>(unauthorized_retry))
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Standard Error

   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:15:9
   |
13 |     fn send_and_expect_wrapper<'a, T>(&'a mut self, unauthorized_retry: i32) 
   |                                    - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `T: 'a`
14 |     -> BoxFuture<'a, std::result::Result<(),()>> {
15 |         Box::pin(self.send_and_expect::<T>(unauthorized_retry))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `impl futures::Future` will meet its required lifetime bounds

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0309`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I have to do   `fn send_and_expect_wrapper<'a, T>(&'a mut self, unauthorized_retry: i32)`

Is there a reason? I never use an instance of `T` so there are no concerns about lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

The type check does *checking on types*. From its point of view, a value only does propagating it's type and triggering actions on the type (such as coercing). And in your example `T` is involved into [*unsized coercion*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions) with `: 'a` bound. Why? [See how `BoxFuture` is declared](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/future/type.BoxFuture.html)

```rust
pub type BoxFuture<'a, T> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T> + Send + 'a, Global>>;
```

Desugared and extremely minimized example would be like:

```rust
pub trait Future {}
struct Closure<'a, T> {
    receiver: &'a mut (),
    params: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}
impl<'a, T> Future for Closure<'a, T> {}
fn foo<'a, T>() {
    let x: *mut Closure<'a, T>;
    let coerced: *mut (dyn Future + 'a) = x;
}
```

This gives the same `error[E0309]`.

The point is in a type checking rule: `U = dyn _ + 'a` implies `U: 'a`. Or simply `(dyn _ + 'a): 'a`

Applying this to our example (`U = Closure<'a, T>`) we get `Closure<'a, T>: 'a` which implies the same bound should hold on the substitutions, i.e. `'a: 'a` and `T: 'a`. But our environment (the `foo` fn signature) tells nothing about the `T: 'a` requirement, hence the error.